# Is socket.getaddrinfo in Python using cache?

Tags: python, sockets, tornado

My application do a lot of RPCs. And got some DNS resolve errors. I found tornado AsyncHttpClient didn't cache dns results, and call socket.getaddrinfo everytime.

I found libraries like  https://github.com/jayvdb/dns-cache

and snippets like

```
def _setDNSCache():
    """
    Makes a cached version of socket._getaddrinfo to avoid subsequent DNS requests.
    """

    def _getaddrinfo(*args, **kwargs):
        if args in kb.cache:
            return kb.cache[args]

        else:
            kb.cache[args] = socket._getaddrinfo(*args, **kwargs)
            return kb.cache[args]

    if not hasattr(socket, "_getaddrinfo"):
        socket._getaddrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo
        socket.getaddrinfo = _getaddrinfo
```

Should I use application-layer dns cache library?

Comment: There is a property called Time to Live (TTL) which is part of the DNS request process. This specifies a time during which the current DNS record is valid and new requests shouldn't be issued. This reduces network requests. Do you feel like the libraries you're using are caching too long or requesting too frequently?

Comment: @vincent thanks very much. I think my app send dns query requests too frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Python does not have its own DNS cache; it will call `getaddrinfo` every time. Whether that call to `getaddrinfo` is cached by the operating system depends on a number of factors. Last time I looked into this it usually wasn't by default, but that was years ago. Installing `dnsmasq` is (or was) the simplest way to get a system-wide DNS cache (that understands and obeys TTLs, etc)